# XMLHttpRequest Url cannot load Url No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angular-services, angular-resource

XMLHttpRequest http://172.ip.ip.ip/employee/record/details cannot load http://172.ip.ip.ip/employee/record/edit/12345. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I tried the below solution which i found googling...
 -  ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' **is already defined on server** still  the same exception :(

Actually its part of an Angular POST Service sending data to server after modification in response to which server should return an object but i am getting **Object [Error error] undefined**

In chrome network Status - **Status Code:500 Internal Server Error**

Any advice, whether changes are required Client side or Server side ??

Answer (score 0):

I am answering it ..

Yes whenever we are getting above error(s) - server changes are required.
Changes that resolved the issue :-

1. If you are using **MVC** then -

Add

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

in

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
}

2. If you are using **Apache**,put this in/create a .htaccess file :-

   ```
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|js|json|html|css)$">
         <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
   </FilesMatch>
   ```

You can add other extensions too..(y)